# Переход на следующий вопрос

Tags: html, php

Впервые пишу на РНР. Вот нужен совет. Есть подобная страничка:
[image]

Подскажите, как оформить переход на след.вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропустили ещё один тег к вопросу: `JavaScript`.
Чтобы отправить данные формы, надо отправлять саму форму.
А чтобы добиться этого при клике на ссылку, придётся перехватывать событие клика с помощью javascript.

Можно упростить задачу, если вместо ссылок поставить кнопки.

Comment: упростила задачу, использовав кнопки

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cur_question = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 0;
$questions = array(0=>"вопрос1",1=>"вопрос2");
echo '<p>'.$questions[$cur_question].'</p>';
echo '<a href="?q='.($cur_question+1).'">next.'</a>';
?>
```

общий смысл такой. Хотя такой код я бы не стал использовать - он показан чисто в образовательных целях. Лучше воспользуйтесь услугами фрилансера, если не собираетесь учить php.

Comment: не. фрилансеры нам не нужны. в колледже щас просто по программе РНР. сижу вот мучаюсь.

Comment: у меня бы php преподавали, я бы радовался...